# XERO Api is forcing to open broswer and click manually on access for 30 minutes button

Tags: c#, oauth, xero-api

I am integrating xero api in my application. I have purchased api. When I request for **oauth_verifier code** using unauthorized token, they are forcing to open web browser. On web page they have link saying that "Allow for 30 minutes". After clicking manually on that link they redirect to callback url with my authentication complete. I want to automate this using api only. Why they are forcing to open browser and click on allow for 30 mins link? 
I have downloaded sample code for C# from [sample code - xero c#](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/libraries/using-the-xero-api-with-c)

[image: Screenshot for page which is xero forcing to open in browser]

Answer (score 1):

The Xero API allows for 30 minute access when using a Public App, as you have noted the user will need to re-authorise every 30 minutes.

A Partner App allows for this process to be automated without user intervention. To be granted a Partner App you will need to get in touch with the Developer Relations team here: https://developer.xero.com/partner/#become-a-partner

Comment: One more question. There are two options for partnership as per link you provided(app partner and developer partner). We want to use xero api to create invoice from my application' code(c#). Can you suggest which partnership program should I go with? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either will put you in touch with the team, but App Partner seems the most appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolute garbage.  Totally circumvents the intent of an api.